# State is Object? for Code Generated Notifier

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I have a Riverpod notifier that has a state object called `AuthState`. However, when I declare my notifier with the code generation tools it is typing state as `object?` instead of `AuthState`. Below is the notifier:

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class AuthService extends _$AuthService {
  late ApiService _apiService;
  late Logger _log;
  final _storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  @override
  build() {
    _apiService = ref.watch(apiServiceProvider);
    _log = ref.watch(loggerProvider);
    return AuthState();
  }

  void testFunc() {
    state = state.copyWith(); // doesn't work because state is Object?
  }
}
```

I can see the culprit is inside my auth_service.g.dart file `final authServiceProvider = NotifierProvider<AuthService, Object?>...`, but I can't find any way to change `Object?` to `AuthResult`

Comment: Always add a type to the return of build().  In general *all* functions should have a declared type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the return type in your build method so the generator can infer the type:

```
@override
AuthState build() { ///Here you declare the return type
    _apiService = ref.watch(apiServiceProvider);
    _log = ref.watch(loggerProvider);
    return AuthState();
  }
```

[image]

For more information check this article: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-riverpod-async-notifier/